# How do I "dockerize" a redis service using phusion/baseimage-docker

Tags: redis, docker

I am getting started with docker, and I am trying by "dockerizing" a simple redis service using Phusion's baseimage. [On its website](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker), baseimage says:

> You can add additional daemons (e.g. your own app) to the image by
>   creating runit entries.

Great, so I first started this image interactively with a cmd of /bin/bash. I installed redis-server via apt-get. I created a "redis-server" directory in /etc/service, and made a runfile that reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf >> /var/log/redis.log 2>&1
```

I ensured that `daemonize` was set to "no" in the `redis.conf` file

I committed my changes, and then with my newly created image, I started it with the following:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 <MY_IMAGE>
```

I see this output:

```
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 98
```

I then run

```
boot2docker ip
```

It gives me back an IP address. But when I run, from my mac,

```
redis-cli -h <IP>
```

It cannot connect. Same with

```
telnet <IP> 6379
```

I ran a docker ps and see the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c7bd2dXXXXXX        myuser/redis:latest          "/sbin/my_init"        11 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   random_name
```

Can anyone suggest what I have done wrong when attempting to dockerize a simple redis service using phusion's baseimage?

Answer (score 1):

It was because I did not comment out the

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

parameter in the `redis.conf` file.

Now, it works!